# Clickable link in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

In my app i am using  **UITextView** to display three lines. In that i need to add link for certain text. I am searched in google and SO, but i couldn't found the exact solution for my problem.

I Tried this but its not working

```
 NSString *testString = @"This will go to <a href = \"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>";
[webview loadHTMLString:testString baseURL:baseURL]; 
[lblLinksTitle setText:testString];
```

I want Google as clickable text which have to open in safari browser. May be its simple. As i am new to **iOS** i couldn't figure out to do this.

Thanks for your help guys.

Much appreciated.

Comment: you should use the `UIWebView` to reach your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use UIWebView, don't use UiTextView

```
 NSString *testString = @"This will go to <a href = \"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>";
 [webview loadHTMLString:testString baseURL:nil];
 webview.delegate=self;



- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{



NSString * requestString=[[request URL] absoluteString];
//NSLog(@"%@ is requestString from clicking",requestString );

if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"http://www.google"]) {


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];


}
    return TRUE;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer if i use web view how can i come back to the view it calls the webview

Comment: UIWebView * webview= [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)]; [self.view addSubView:webview]; I believe webview is your view's subview

Comment: You saying that the webview is fixed at certain place.. if i click google it will opened in that webview.. right.. but i would like to open as like browser and so i can come back to myview

Comment: uiweb view has an return event , you link it with a button

Comment: you got to use UIWebViewDelegate to catch the click event

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
lblLinksTitle.editable = NO;
lblLinksTitle.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
lblLinksTitle.text = testString;
```

Comment: I tried yours but it displaying as a link with all html tag in it what i want is the link have to hide behind the word as like hyperlink..

Comment: @Vinoth without using a UIWebView or a private API, this is not possible, sorry.